# Hide report or hide search icon for user

Tags: dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

Is there a way I can hide a report for a particular user in business central cloud. Or just hide the search icon for the user. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Permission Sets. Here is how:

1. Copy the permission set where the user currently belongs to.
2. While on the permission set add your object as report and key in your report
   ID(as below) and set execute permission to indirect.
3. Now go to the corresponding table object, and set the read permissions to
   indirect.
   In my case, I wanted to restrict the report on chart of accounts, so in my permission set I added my report ID with execute permission as indirect. Then added the table G/L account with read permissions as indirect.

With this, the user will see the report but won't be able to run it.

The alternative is to create a boolean under user setup and add a control on the report that it only runs when the boolean is true for that user.

You can read more on another scenario here: https://community.dynamics.com/business/f/dynamics-365-business-central-forum/421079/removing-access-to-pages-and-reports-from-permission-sets

[image]